# Visual Studio 2013 IIS Express Crashes every time when attaching with Toad SQL Tracker IIS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, crash, iis-express, toad

In Visual Studio 2013, when debugging MVC application with Oracle 11g as the backend, IIS Express crashes.

In Toad, after attaching SQL Tracker to IIS Express process, going back to the application and accessing any page, app crash window appears, details of the crash is shown below. We have recently upgraded our application from VS 2010 (development server) to VS 2013 (IIS Express), it is still working fine in the VS 2010 solution (development server). It is only failing in VS 2013 (IIS Express).

We are not sure, how to get it working, Any help would be much appreciated?

**Faulting application name:** iisexpress.exe, version: 8.5.9748.0, time stamp: 0x5384d451 
**Faulting module name:** sqlmon_dll32.dll, version: 3.0.0.57, time stamp: 0x4ba17b04 
**Exception code:** 0xc00000fd 
**Fault offset:** 0x0002da77 
**Faulting process id:** 0x3244 
**Faulting application start time:** 0x01d0849f4669931c
**Faulting application path:** *C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe* 
**Faulting module path:** *C:\Dell\Toad for Oracle 10.6\SQLTracker\sqlmon_dll32.dll* 
**Report Id:** 9e356b80-f092-11e4-8c91-fc4dd43e5a99

Answer (score 0):

We had the same problem and figured that it was toad which needed to reinstalled. Do a clean up and reinstall.